# Callback function will not call other member functions of its class

Tags: angular, typescript

My callback function will not call another member function of the same class instance

Using typescript in angular, I have a class that defines a public member  function `myCallback()` that is passed to a ngrx store subscription as a callback function, and called asynchronously. The `myCallback()` function attempts to call another member function `this.funcA()` of its same class instance,  but this fails with the error that `funcA()` is not defined.

The `myCallback()` can call member properties `this.prop` of its same class instance, and can call functions that are not members of the same class, example `funcB()`.

I suspect this has something to do with the `this` context changing. But I can call properties successfully using `this`, but not functions ??

What is going on here, what am i not understanding?

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit
{
  public prop:boolean;
  private sub:Subscriber;
  constructor(public storeY:Store<fromY.FeatureState>){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.sub = new Subscriber(this.storeY);
    this.sub.myCallback = this.myCallback;
    this.sub.subscribe();
} 

  public myCallback()
  {
    this.prop=true; //works
    this.funcA(); //does not work, funcA not defined
    funcB(); //works
  }

  public funcA()
  {}
} //end class

funcB(){}
```

The abbreviated subscriber class

```
export class Subscriber  {
  public myCallback: () => void;
  constructor(public storeY:Store<fromY.FeatureState>) 
  { }

  public subscribe() //called in external ngOnInit 
  {
    this.storeY.select(state => state.myData)
    .pipe()
    .subscribe((data:object) =>{
      this.myCallback(); //calling callback
    }
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Did you try fat arrow function: myCallback = () => {}

Comment: Because `this` changes depending on the scope so this.funcA() is defined when you're calling the function myCallback directly from ngOnInit (for example) but it will be undefined when you're calling it from other class in a callback

Answer (score 5):

This is a context issue.

By writing

```
 this.sub.myCallback = this.myCallback;
```

You change the context of the caller : the `this` keyword now references something else, in this case it is the `sub` variable.

Use `bind` to bind the correct context to your element :

```
this.sub.myCallback = this.myCallback.bind(this)
```